# Javascript validation works on localhost but not on amazon ec2 (same files)

Tags: javascript, html, validation, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just uploaded the file structure as it is to my EC2 instance. Same form file and same javascript validation file.

Validation works perfectly on localhost but not on EC2 and I am unable to figure out what is going wrong. I checked the directory structure, hrefs and links and they look ok to me.

Following is the Javascript file:

```
    //Calling the validate function when user submits form
window.load = function() {
  var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
  myForm.onsubmit = function(e) {
      return validate();
  }  
}

//Validation funtion
function validate() {

    var product_name = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["pname"].value;
    var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var phone = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
    var price = document.forms["myForm"]["price"].value;
    var date22 = document.forms["myForm"]["date22"].value;
    var description = document.forms["myForm"]["description"].value;

    var d = new Date();
    var values=date22.split("-");
    makeWhite();

    if (product_name==null || product_name == "" ) {
        makeRed('fname');
        alert("Enter Product Name");
        return false;}
    else if (name == null || name == ""|| isNaN(name) == false) {
        makeRed('pname');
        alert("Enter valid name");
        return false;       
    }
    else if(email == '' || email.indexOf('@') == -1 || email.indexOf('.') == -1) 
    {
        makeRed('email');
        alert("Insert valid Email Address");
        return false;   
        }
    else if(phone == ''|| phone <1000000000 || phone >9999999999){
        makeRed('phone');
        alert("Enter valid phone number");
        return false;   

        }
        else if(price == ''|| price <0 || price >9999999999){
        makeRed('price');
        alert("Enter valid cost");
        return false;   

        }
        else if(description == ''|| description == null){
        makeRed('description');
        alert("Enter a description");
        return false;   

        }

        else if(values[0]=="" || values[0]==null||values[0]>d.getFullYear() || values[1]> 1+d.getMonth() || values[2]>d.getDate()){
        makeRed('date22');
        alert("Please Check Date");
    return false;
    }   
}

//Function to make invalid input fields red 
function makeRed(inputDiv){
var div= document.getElementById(inputDiv);
div.style.backgroundColor="#FFA07A";
div.style.border = "2px solid #FF0000   ";
return false;
}

//Function to clear fields when input is valid
function makeWhite(){
var divList = document.querySelectorAll(".inputField");
for (var i=0;i<divList.length;i++){
divList[i].style.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF";
divList[i].style.border = "1px solid #BDBDBD";
}
return false;
}
```

References to the JS file:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/carouFredSel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js_validation.js"></script>
```

Comment: This code is all running in the browser. It makes no difference where it is loading from, localhost or EC2 or anywhere else. I suggest you open your browser developer console and learn to debug your JavaScript. I'm guessing some file wasn't copied to EC2 correctly and so the browser is unable to load it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that the files are actually loading? I could see an issue with `js/jquery.js` vs `/js/jquery.js`